# Preserving input value regardless of validation with input type="number"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stumbling upon weird case while using angularJs and input type="number". Basically, if I have input with type number and initial value falls outside range defined by min and max, my initial value is simply destroyed.

I've made fiddle to illustrate the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/PK3QH/2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="bindData.SomeAmount" type="number" required="required" />
    <br />
    <input ng-model="bindData.SomeAmount" type="number" required="required" 
        min="2" max="10" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.bindData = {
        SomeAmount: 1
    };
}
```

As you can see first textbox works without any problems, but the second one simply doesn't display the value. I definitely need value to be preserved while also being validated as number in certain range - so is there any way our this?

Comment: why is that surprising? Why even call it a bug when it works as expected?

Comment: Yea, I agree with the @mplungjan. It sure seems that would the behavior you would *want* to have happen.

Comment: Well, the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) say that it raises a validation error -- so an option would be to disable validation with the `novalidate` option (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). I'd assume you want validation though in any other case...

Comment: Please let's not get into semantics, I'll edit question to remove word "bug". But I hope everyone understands that I want value to be preserved if it's valid number, not destroyed.

Comment: So basically you don't want to validate the range, right? Why are you using the `min` and `max` attributes, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree this is a bug.

This happens because the formatters are applied first before validators. 
The formatter in the case of 'number'

```
  if (attr.min) {
    var minValidator = function(value) {
      var min = parseFloat(attr.min);
      return validate(ctrl, 'min', ctrl.$isEmpty(value) || value >= min, value);
    };

    ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
    **ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);**
  }
```

all the $formatters are run first before the validators are run initially...checkout NgModelController.

I wonder if the "first" time when $dirty != true if they applied the formaters based on validity i.e. let the formatters yield if the validation results to false.

In the case of minNumber the formatter should be only a number. Why do we need a formatter for minNumber ?

Raised it https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8264

Until the Angular team fixes this short term solution would be to use your own directive instead of min.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to raise issue and respond. I'll accept answer as is until this is resolved by Angular team.

Comment: Also watch out for another issue for type=number - if you have a `<input type="number"/>` and the initial value from the model is `NaN` (say String) you will see the same "lost" behavior you mentioned. Angular team is working on decoupling the validators, formatters and parsers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is a bug.

If you remove ng-model attribute, you see the initial value.

If this is NOT a bug, when we type invalid value such as 40, we must not see the entered text as it happend as when initialized. See, it's not consistent.

It only happens for the first time when input directive is initialized.

IMO, Even though, the model value is not value, it should preserve the original value by not setting to blank.

Sorry for not providing solution.